# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace in java spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new in java spring web framework. I am trying to run an existing project to learn about spring framework. But I am encountering a problem while trying to run that project in my machine. It shows a configuration error. I am running this on `java 1.7` and with `maven 2.2`

**Error**

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]
Offending resource: file [E:\CeylonExchangeHandover\New\cex-server\WebContent\WEB-INF\cex-service-servlet.xml]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
at com.cex.client.RestClient.getTemplate(RestClient.java:79)
at com.cex.client.RestClient.main(RestClient.java:24)
```

My `pom.xml` file looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cex</groupId>
<artifactId>cex-service</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate-version>3.6.3.Final</hibernate-version>
    <commons-dbcp-version>1.4</commons-dbcp-version>
    <target.environment>dev</target.environment>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
<artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
      <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
             <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
             <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
             <version>${commons-dbcp-version}</version>
         </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL for c: tag -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson for json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate Validator - implementation of Bean Validation JSR 303-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/cex-service-servlet.xml</webXml>
                <warName>cex-service</warName>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>                    
                <!--<containerConfigXML>src/main/config/dev/context.xml</containerConfigXML>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="###################    Using config files for environment [${target.environment}]"/>
                            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties"/>
                            <!--<copy file="src/main/config/application.${target.environment}.properties" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />-->
                            <copy toDir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/config/${target.environment}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                            </copy>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <target.environment>dev</target.environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <target.environment>test</target.environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <target.environment>prod</target.environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And `csx-service-servlets.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>cex-service</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cex-service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cex-service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!--
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/CexDB</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/serverCexDB</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
-->
</web-app>
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: You are trying to load your `web.xml` as a Spring file that is obviously not going to work. `web.xml` !- `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: This project is running on development server, but i cannot run it in my local machine. My project is built  successfully but it shows error on runtime.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it runs your configuration is weird and spring is trying to load the web.xml as an application context file. That is n't going to work. It tries to load it l ike that because of your weird setup.